# Recoloring 16x16 Sprites to Nearest Color in Custom Palette

Tags: python, image, hex, rgb

I have a folder containing a collection of 16x16 pixel sprites, and I'd like to recolor each sprite by replacing its colors with the nearest matching color from a custom palette I obtained from https://lospec.com/palette-list/duel. For example, if I have a sprite with a random brown color, I want to change it to the closest brown color available in my palette.

What would be an efficient way to achieve this color replacement using Python or any other programming language? Is there a specific library or algorithm that can help me map the original colors to the nearest color in my custom palette while preserving the overall appearance of the sprites? Any code examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated.